# Informatica Target Table Keyword

Tags: informatica

How do you use Informatica to load data into a target table whose name is a SQL reserved keyword?

I have a situation where I am trying to use Informatica to populate a table called **Union** which is failing with the following error:

- SQL Server Message: Incorrect syntax near the keywork 'Union'
- Database driver error...
- Function Name : Execute Multiple
- SQL Stmt : INSERT INTO UNION (UnionCode, UnionName, etc )

I have been told that changing the database properties to use quoted identifier would solve this problem; however, I have tried that and it only appears to work for sources, not targets.

And before anyone states the obvious - I cannot change the name of the target table.

Comment: could you write into a view?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try overriding the table name in session properties as "Union" with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Load your data in a table with valid name  ,having same structure as union  . 
And in Post Sql of that target, you can rename the table with whatever name required .

Ex . 
Click on the target (XUnion) , 
go to Post Sql and  put statement below --

```
RENAME XUnion to 'UNION' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If any table name or column name contains a database reserved word, such as MONTH or YEAR, the session fails with database errors when the Integration Service executes SQL against the database. You can create and maintain a reserved words file, reswords.txt, in the server/bin directory. When the Integration Service initializes a session, it searches for reswords.txt. If the file exists, the Integration Service places quotes around matching reserved words when it executes SQL against the database.

Use the following rules and guidelines when working with reserved words.

The Integration Service searches the reserved words file when it generates SQL to connect to source, target, and lookup databases.

If you override the SQL for a source, target, or lookup, you must enclose any reserved word in quotes.

You may need to enable some databases, such as Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase, to use SQL-92 standards regarding quoted identifiers. Use connection environment SQL to issue the command. For example, use the following command with Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

Sample reswords.txt File 
To use a reserved words file, create a file named reswords.txt and place it in the server/bin directory. Create a section for each database that you need to store reserved words for. Add reserved words used in any table or column name. You do not need to store all reserved words for a database in this file. Database names and reserved words in reswords.txt are not case sensitive.

Following is a sample reswords.txt file:

[Teradata] MONTH DATE INTERVAL [Oracle] OPTION START [DB2] [SQL Server] CURRENT [Informix] [ODBC] MONTH [Sybase]